# webstorm javascript function trace/data flow

Tags: javascript, intellij-13

I am currently using Intellij webstorm for front end development. I am considering is that possible that I could analyse the function trace using this powerful IDE. For example, I have a file within a project which contains more than 100 functions and I am trying to understand the sequence of functions execution. So far, I can only find the function which executed first and see how this function calls the other functions (sometime I can only manually add break points for analysing), but this is very painful especially there are some many functions and one function will call several other functions as well.

I know in the Intellij Idea (Java), we can use something like "data flow to this" which will show the sequence of functions execution. How about Javascript? I believe you guys must have the same situations as I do and how do you guys analyse this?

Many thanks for this!